# What are the names of betoh16/32 and letoh16/32 on Linux?

Tags: c, bit, endianness

As the title suggests, what are names of `letoh16`, `letoh32`, `betoh16`, and `betoh32` on Linux? I have found `htonl`, but that doesn't let me choose 16 bit or 32 bit, and it is also only to big endianess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions are called the following on Linux:

- `letoh16` is called `le16toh`
- `letoh32` is called `le32toh`
- `betoh16` is called `be16toh`
- `betoh32` is called `be32toh`